# HTML dont submit select with given option

Tags: html, forms, submit

I want option ccc to be selectable, but not submitted, so when someone submit form with option ccc selected, all `<select>` should not be sent.

HTML only solution would be best.

```
<select name="some">
   <option>aaa</option> //send
   <option>bbb</option> //send
   <option special>ccc</option> //dont send
</select>
```

Comment: I believe you can't do that with only HTML

Comment: You need javascript for that

Comment: HTML only solution would be to ignore the select option on the server

Comment: One way to do it in HTML would be to only put aaa and bbb in the form, then put ccc in another form which you could just position to make it look like they are all part of the same form. ugly, but would solve your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot prevent the `select` submission without removing or disabling it prior to form submission using javascript.

Having said that, it makes much more sense to test for this on the *server* side, and this is actually done regularly when no option is selected, like so:

```
<select name="some">
   <option value="-1">Select an option</option> 
   <option value="aaa">aaa</option> 
   <option value="bbb">bbb</option> 
</select>
```

PHP:

```
if ($_POST['some']!=-1) {
  // do something
}
```

Answer (score 1):

With HTML only, the field will always be submitted. However you can post an empty value, giving practically the same effect:

```
<select name="some">
   <option value="aaa">aaa</option>
   <option value="bbb">bbb</option>
   <option value="">ccc</option> //empty value
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

Using Only HTML you can

```html
<form action="#" method="POST">
<select name="some" required>
    <option selected value="">ccc</option> //empty value
    <option value="aaa">aaa</option> //send
    <option value="bbb">bbb</option> //send
</select>

<input type="submit" name="submit">
</form>
```

Comment: Read the question again: "I want option ccc to be selectable". `ccc` is selected in your example, but cannot be re-selected after `aaa` or `bbb` was selected cause it's disabled.

Comment: -After Edit- Now the option is selectable and will not be submitted

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
<select name="some">
   <option value="aaa">aaa</option> //send
   <option value="bbb">bbb</option> //send
   <option>ccc</option> //dont send
</select>
```

If I'm correct this should return nothing when you send the form with ccc selected.

Comment: This is incorrect. In case one doesn't specify the value, it would default to the text inside the option. So in this case the value would be "ccc"